# selecting the rows based on the distinct column values

Tags: sql, oracle

I have the following data in a table `sample`. I am using Oracle database.

---

```
column1      column2         column3
A             01           2017-07-27-04.24.58.851340
B             01           2017-07-27-06.43.19.654420
C             01           2017-08-10-08.26.47.633480
```

I need to pull out the count of distinct records based on `SUBSTR(column3, 1,10)` value.

For example:

In the first row, 
the `SUBSTR(column3, 1,10)` value of `column3` is `2017-07-27`,

In the second row,
the `SUBSTR(column3, 1,10)` value of `column3` is `2017-07-27` which is same as first row

In third row, the `SUBSTR(column3, 1,10)` value of `column3` is `2017-08-10` which is different from first two rows.

So  based on distinct `SUBSTR(column3, 1,10)` values, the count should be returned as `2`.

Can anybody help me out?

Comment: If `column3` has a datatype of `Timestamp`, why not get the `COUNT` of `DATE` part rather than doing a `SUBSTR`. Even if it is string, try to convert it to `TIMESTAMP` and apply the suggested option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select count(distinct SUBSTR(column3, 1,10))
from sample
```

Comment: That's simple and perfect solution. +1 for your quick response

Answer (score 2):

Since you appear to be storing timestamp values as strings (which you should not do, and ought to store them as timestamps) you can convert them to a timestamp and then truncate the time component to the start of the day:

```
SELECT   COUNT( DISTINCT TRUNC( TO_TIMESTAMP( column3, 'YYYY-MM-DD-HH24.MI.SS.FF6' ) ) )
           AS num_days
FROM     your_table
```

But you could also just use the string value:

```
SELECT   COUNT( DISTINCT SUBSTR( column3, 1, 10 ) ) AS num_days
FROM     your_table
```

If you convert your table to store them as timestamps then you can just use:

```
SELECT   COUNT( DISTINCT TRUNC( column3 ) ) AS num_days
FROM     your_table
```

Comment: Yes.. we are storing as strings in database and I am not supposed to alter the design. Thanks for your explanation. +1 for it.